# Assert stuff about mocked Python class instances

Tags: python, mocking

Suppose I have mock_class.py:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def print_value(self):
        print(f'my value is: {self.value}')


def fubar(values):
    for value in values:
        some_class = SomeClass(value)
        some_class.print_value()
```

And test_mock_class.py:

```
from unittest import mock

import mock_class


@mock.patch('mock_class.SomeClass')
def test_fubar(mock_some_class):
    mock_class.fubar(['a', 'b'])
    assert mock_some_class.call_args_list == [
        mock.call('a'),
        mock.call('b'),
    ]
```

Is it possible to assert `print_value` was called on each instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return from that function the assertion expression:

```
def print_value(self):
    print(f'my value is: {self.value}')
    return True
```

Then assert in your mock class:

```
def fubar(values):
    for value in values:
        some_class = SomeClass(value)
        assert some_class.print_value()
```

Comment: I'd rather not return a value just for the test, but even with that, what I want to do in my test (not in the application code `fubar`) is to assert that `print_value` was called on each instance of `SomeClass` that was created.